# SELECT 1 percent of distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

SQL Server 2008 R2

I have a table called Actions, this would be a snippet of what it looks like

```
ActionID | ActionType | ActionUserID | ActionDateTime
---------+------------+--------------+---------------------
555363     Open         9843           2020-09-15 09:27:55
555364     Process      2563           2020-09-15 09:31:22
555365     Close        8522           2020-09-15 09:37:48
555366     Detour       9843           2020-09-15 09:42:42
555367     Process      9843           2020-09-15 09:51:50
555368     Close        8522           2020-09-15 09:55:45
555369     Open         1685           2020-09-15 09:57:12
555370     Detour       2563           2020-09-15 10:03:23
555371     Detour       9843           2020-09-15 10:04:33
555372     Close        8522           2020-09-15 10:07:44
```

The table has hundreds of thousands of rows.  What I want to do is review 1% of all actions performed by each user for a specific month.

I know I can get 1% of everything by doing:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 PERCENT * 
FROM Actions 
WHERE ActionDateTime BETWEEN '09/01/2020' AND '09/30/2020' 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

I know I can get 1% of a specific user by doing:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 PERCENT * 
FROM Actions 
WHERE ActionUserID = 9843 
  AND ActionDateTime BETWEEN '09/01/2020' AND '09/30/2020' 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

But what I really want to get is 1% of each user.  I know I could get a list of the users who performed actions during the month by doing:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(ActionUserID) 
WHERE ActionDateTime BETWEEN '09/01/2020' AND '09/30/2020'
```

However I am not sure how to combine these two queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what I really want to get is 1% of each user.

I would recommend window function `percent_rank()`:

```
select *
from (
    select a.*, percent_rank() over(partition by actionuserid order by newid()) prn
    from actions a
    where actiondatetime >= '20200901' and actiondatetime < '20201001'
) a
where prn < 0.01
```

If your version of SQL Server is so old that it does not support `percent_rank()`, then we can emulate it with `rank()` and `count()`:

```
select *
from (
    select a.*, 
        rank() over(partition by actionuserid order by newid()) as rn,
        count(*) over(partition by actionuserid) as cnt
    from actions a
    where actiondatetime >= '20200901' and actiondatetime < '20201001'
) a
where 100.0 * rn / cnt  < 1 or (rn = 1 and cnt < 100)
```

Comment: Looks like percent_rank was added in SQL 2012, I am still on 2008 R2.

Comment: @Pryach: 2008 is a very old version... Nevertheless, see my update.

Comment: The emulation is not the same. With `percent_rank` you always get at least one row. With emulation you get no rows if you have less than 100 rows in partition.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek: that's a good point. I attempted to fix the query to handle that edge case.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily combine the two queries using CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ActionUserID 
    WHERE ActionDateTime BETWEEN '09/01/2020' AND '09/30/2020'
) u
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 PERCENT * 
    FROM Actions a
    WHERE a.ActionUserID = u.ActionUserID 
    AND ActionDateTime BETWEEN '09/01/2020' AND '09/30/2020' 
    ORDER BY NEWID()
) a
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it is a little beat easier to understand but it takes a lot longer to run than GMB's query.

Comment: Yes, for this particular case. But the pattern of CROSS APPLY is still very useful.